# Use local variable with concatenation in Org mode

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

I am trying to somehow use a local variable in org-mode for when I write my R code. So essentially in have this chunk that I want to automatically manage for each file.

```
#+BEGIN_SRC R :file /Users/ashok/Documents/plots/wtdup.png
  pairs.panels(tmpDat.cpm.log[,c(1:4,17:20)],)
#+END_SRC
```

in the chunk above I want to be able to replace the value for the :file with a path to the plots folder that could change. So I tried to use the local variable approach as below

```
 * LOCAL VARS
## Local Variables:
## mode: org
## plotfolder: "/Users/DataAnalysis/FinalAnalysisMay2016/plots"
## End:
```

and then replace the :file parameter with

```
#+BEGIN_SRC R :file (eval 'plotfolder)"/truseq_comp_logcpm_pairwise_wtdup.png"
  pairs.panels(tmpDat.cpm.log[,c(5,7,8,21:23)], )
#+END_SRC
```

Now when I evaluate the chunk ( after reverting my buffer to make the local variable active), the result includes only the value of the plotfolder variable and not the concatenated version as I wanted. 
in this case my results would show up as

```
#+RESULTS
/Users/DataAnalysis/FinalAnalysisMay2016/plots
```

but what i really want is

```
#+RESULTS
/Users/DataAnalysis/FinalAnalysisMay2016/plots/truseq_comp_logcpm_pairwise_wtdup.png
```

If anyone has any suggestions as to how I can go about this it would be great, since then I can move the same files between machines when I am working on cleaning up the results.

Comment: `(concat plotfolder "/truseq_comp_logcpm_pairwise_wtdup.png")` ?

Comment: I tried that and I get the "symbols function definition is void" error

Answer (score 1):

Got it i used the emacs concat function as suggested by @phils above but i had to figure out how it was evaluated. Here is the solution

```
#+BEGIN_SRC R :file (concat (eval plot folder) "/truseq_comp_logcpm_pairwise_wtdup.png")
  pairs.panels(tmpDat.cpm.log[,c(5,7,8,21:23)], )
#+END_SRC
```

To summarize. Say you wanted to specify a variable text in org-mode then in the example above add plotfolder to the local variables as mentioned and then use concat as above to add say prefixes or suffixes